# How to split an Array of Strings to another array with respect to lines?

Tags: arrays

So I am trying to get a list a list of WebElements to an Array of String. I have written the below code, which is helping me to get the WebElements to an array

**Code** -

```
    List<WebElement> statusLabelSection = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='MuiGrid-root paboxLayout MuiGrid-item']//table"));

    List<String> stringsOutput = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    for(WebElement ele:statusLabelSection) {
        stringsOutput.add(ele.getText());
    }

    System.out.println(stringsOutput);
```

**Output** –

[Not Required

0001F - Code Recovery Composite

Recovery Which That May Apply

None

Additional static Information

None]

Problem Statement -

I want the output to be in an array like this

**expected** -

[Not Required, 0001F - Code Recovery Composite, Recovery Which That May Apply, None, Additional static Information, None]

Can you please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the best way but solved it. Any feedback to improvise is welcome!!!
`code`

```
    List<WebElement> statusLabelSection = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='MuiGrid-root paboxLayout MuiGrid-item']//table"));
    List<String> stringsOutput = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(WebElement ele: statusLabelSection) {
        stringsOutput.add(ele.getText());
    }
    
    String str = stringsOutput.get(0).toString();
    String[] inputArr = str.split("\n");
    for (int i=0; i<inputArr.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("num " + i + " - "+ inputArr[i]);
    }
```